# React Router Component not re rendering when changing child routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have set the Routes as below:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/example" element={<Example />}>
        <Route path=":id" element={<Another />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

My Problem is when I visit `/example/1` from `/example` page directly. The content of `<Another />` renders correctly. But if I try to visit for example `/example/1` while I am on `/example/2` the URL changes on the browser but the content of the page does not change.
I am using `useParms()` hook in `<Another />` component to generate dynamic content.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you add more of your code, Especially `<Another />` component code